# Displaying a Scratch Project (.SB) file within a Delphi EXE FIle

Tags: delphi, exe, delphi-xe7, mit-scratch, delphi-ide

I would like to Display a [Scratch Project](http://wiki.scratch.mit.edu/wiki/Scratch_File_Format_%281.4%29/Project_File) (.SB) file within my Delphi EXE file. I would like to know if it is possible to display and build the Scratch Project into your Delphi Project.

I wish to make a small game in [Scratch](http://scratch.mit.edu/) and then use the game within my Delphi Application without the need of the Scratch IDE. Perhaps a 3rd party delphi tool or component or something that can help me achieve this would also be nice.

Is this possible?
How can this be done?

Comment: You wish to host scratch inside your Delphi app? I doubt that is possible.

Comment: The [1.4 API](http://wiki.scratch.mit.edu/wiki/Scratch_API_%281.4%29) looks to exists only for querying the website; no luck there IMO.

Comment: Yes, I wish to display and host the Scratch project inside my Delphi App.

Comment: What has your research yielded so far?

Comment: I couldn't find anything.

Comment: There's an abhorrent lack of technical documentation (probably because it seems designed for small children) but it looks like it might be browser based (HTML5?).  Could you just host a WebBrowser control in your application if so?

Comment: @J... It's not browser based. It's a Java app.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan ...but does it run in browser?  It looks like an online IDE to me.  Does `TWebBrowser` or `TChromium` allow hosting java applets?  That's about the closest thing I can dream of that might be a solution.

Comment: @J... I suppose that's possible. I think you'd need to get the source and try.

Comment: It really doesn't matter how I display it. As long as it can be displayed and used inside my Delphi Application without the need of the Scratch IDE.

Comment: @J... It's Flash, not Java.

Comment: @Scimonster That works too - as long as the web browser component can render it then it should work.

Comment: Ok, so how do I let the TWebBrowser component render it? Because currently the Scratch File is .SB and I will need to put it within the EXE or it can even be read from the files, but it needs to be displayed in the App somehow.

Comment: I am really curious as to what the point of having it in your application is.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible, like everything, but it's not been done AFAIK, which means it's going to be hard work.

You have a few choices:

- Scratch is normally embedded within web sites as a Flash object. If
  you can embed Flash media, that is a solution.
- Some Scratch-inspired systems like BYOB export to exe. You could look    into how they do that to use your project (Scratch and BYOB
  are    compatible *enough* to load your project and export it after
  minor changes)
- If you don't like these, then write your own Scratch interpreter for Delphi. Scratch sprites are objects, their behaviour is straightforward enough, the Scratch projects are easily parsed (it's XML), now - off you go!

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you want to port a scratch program to .EXE.
If this is the case, then you can install [BYOB](http://snap.berkeley.edu/).
After doing this, you can [convert your scratch project](http://djdolphin.github.io/Snapin8r2/) to a BYOB project and load it into BYOB.
Then, go to Share->Compile this project, and it will generate a .EXE for you.